# Get-InstalledModule -AllowPrerelease not listing the prereleases?

Tags: powershell, package-management

I'm currently working on a script that automatically updates a package with error handling. I also want it to recognize prerelease packages. For that, I'm using the "Get-InstalledModule" command with its switch parameter -AllowPrerelease. But it's just giving me the major releases?

The versions installed:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-InstalledModule -Name BcContainerHelper -AllVersions

Version              Name                                Repository           Description                                                                   
-------              ----                                ----------           -----------                                                                   
2.0.10               BcContainerHelper                   PSGallery            PowerShell module                                                             
2.0.11-preview422    BcContainerHelper                   PSGallery            PowerShell module                                                             
2.0.5                BcContainerHelper                   PSGallery            PowerShell module
```

I want the newest prerelease, but instead it gives me the latest major?

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Get-InstalledModule -Name BcContainerHelper -AllowPrerelease

Version              Name                                Repository           Description                                                                   
-------              ----                                ----------           -----------                                                                   
2.0.10               BcContainerHelper                   PSGallery            PowerShell module
```

Is that intended or did I do something wrong?

Comment: I don't know why but my Hi was cut off? So Hi guys!

Comment: It's unnecessary noise and would have been removed by a community editor.

Comment: I agree with you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, `-AllowPrelease` does nothing in `Get-InstalledModule` [per MS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/gallery/concepts/module-prerelease-support?view=powershell-7.1):

> If -AllowPrerelease flag is not specified, prerelease packages will
> not be shown.
>
> The only exceptions to this in the PowerShellGet module commands are
> Get-InstalledModule, and some cases with Uninstall-Module.
>
> Get-InstalledModule always will automatically show the prerelease
> information in the version string for modules.

I have the same behavior as you, but this will return the latest prerelease versions:

```
(Get-InstalledModule $name -AllVersions | sort version -Descending)[0]`
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I'll try that out tomorrow!